# Auto reload a page using JS, with a checkbox to enable/disable the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload

HTML

```
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(10000);">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="autoRefreshCheckboxes" >Auto Refresh</input>
</body>
```

JS

```
  function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        if ($("input[name=autoRefreshCheckboxes]").is(":checked")) {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeoutPeriod);
        }
    }
```

How can I make the checkbox work? 


It seems that when the `<body>` loads, it takes the state of the checkbox, and ignores the state of the checkbox when the script is run.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `setInterval` instead.

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    var interval = setInterval(refreshPage, timeoutPeriod);
}

function refreshPage() {
    if ($("input[name=autoRefreshCheckboxes]").is(":checked")) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
```